# Regex to Allow a Special Character (:) and numbers and alphabets only

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS directive for my form input validation .Is there a way to make my regex allow only one special character(:)along with numbers and alphabets . This is the directive i found on stackoverflow.

```
        myapp.directive('noSpecialChar', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == null)
                    return ''
                    cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
                    cleanInputValue = cleanInputValue.toUpperCase();
                if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
                    modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
                    modelCtrl.$render();
                }
                return cleanInputValue;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I tried adding colon at the end , but i'm unable to reach my solution .

Comment: Try `.replace(/^([^:]*:)|[^\w\s]/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1.replace(/[^\w\s]+/g,'')+':' : ''; })` instead of `.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your current code, you're looking to replace everything that is not a letter, number, or white space character.

That said, the regex `[^\w\s:]` should work.

`\w` = a-z, A-Z, 0-9

`\s` = white space characters \r\n\t\f\v

I would even consider removing the `\s` as it would allow spaces in your input, unless that is your intention.

Comment: NO i dont want spaces to be allowed. I just want colon to be allowed along with \w = a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Comment: Ok, then you would want to use `[^\w:]` only then.  `\s` matches whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.replace(/^([^:]*:)|\W/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1.replace(/\W+/g,'')+':' : ''; })` instead of `.replace(/\W/gi, '')`

See the following demo:

```js
var s = "(*a word : 156,567-354 *)";
console.log(s.replace(/^([^:]*:)|\W/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1.replace(/\W+/g,'')+':' : ''; }));
```

The `/^([^:]*:)|[^\w\s]/g`  regex will match and capture into Group 1 0+ chars other than `:` and a `:`, OR will match any char that is not a word or whitespace. If Group 1 matched, the whole contents is stripped from the chars other than word and whitespace chars and a `:` is added, else, the matched chars with `[^\w\s]` are removed.

Comment: I dont want the white space too. is there a way i could do that

Comment: You want to remove all whitespace? I edited the answer. The main point is to replace `[^\w\s]` with `\W` as `\W` matches anything but word chars, while the `[^\w\s]` matches any char other than a word and a whitespace char.